# Permission denied with django app under Yosemite

Tags: django, macos, apache, osx-yosemite

I have a django app that I have been running on Mountain Lion (OSX 10.8) and I upgraded my machine to Yosemite (10.10.5). I read about the differences between apache version 2.2 and 2.4, and I made the indicated changed to my config file, and the app mostly works. The one issue I am having is that my images are not being served - I am getting a 403 permission denied.

Here is the relevant section of my config file:

```
alias /archive /usr/local/motor/data
<location "/archive">
    SetHandler None
</location>
<directory "/usr/motor/archive">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    Require all granted
</directory>
```

The files and dirs are all 644 and 755, but I get:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /archive/KA17/28Feb12/Images/11193LPA002.000_PARM1DPOR_2/MeasDisplay/PARM1DPOR_RUN1_PARM1DPOR_XLS_M1_FX0_FY-1_RR1_TR1_Ver1.jpg on this server.

$ ls -l /usr/local/motor/data/KA17/28Feb12/Images/11193LPA002.000_PARM1DPOR_2/MeasDisplay/PARM1DPOR_RUN1_PARM1DPOR_XLS_M1_FX0_FY-1_RR1_TR1_Ver1.jpg
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff  77738 Oct  6  2012 /usr/local/motor/data/KA17/28Feb12/Images/11193LPA002.000_PARM1DPOR_2/MeasDisplay/PARM1DPOR_RUN1_PARM1DPOR_XLS_M1_FX0_FY-1_RR1_TR1_Ver1.jpg
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You seem to be setting access configuration in Apache for `/usr/motor/archive`, but you're actually serving from `/usr/local/motor/data`.

Comment: Thanks. Adding a directive for /usr/local/motor/data fixed it.